# Returning all collections relational table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Im retrieding all the data related with a specific object, but instead of getting only the data related with the product is getting me all the data from the table.

Controller:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
return $product->with('detailsProduct')->get();
```

Model Product:

```
public function detailsProduct(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductTranslation::class);
    }
```

Comment: Does `Product::with('detailsProduct')->find($id)` return the same result? If so what are the columns in the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
$product = Product::with('detailsProduct')->where('id', $id)->first();
return $product;
```

Comment: You can also do `$product = Product::with('detailsProduct')->find($id);`. However, while this does solve the OP's issue, please add an explanation as to why it solves the issue. Without an explanation, no one will learn from this answer.